# Not displayed correctly in elementUI Cascader

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

I use elementUI's cascading selector to display the data, I wrote this code according to the official documentation.

```
  <el-cascader
    v-model="address"
    :options="addressOptions"
    :props="{expandTrigger: 'hover'}"
  ></el-cascader>

  data() {
    return {
      address: '',
      addressOptions: [
        {
          value: 'Beijing',
          label: 'Beijing',
          children: this.getOptions("Beijing")
        },
        {
          value: 'Shanghai',
          label: 'Shanghai',
          children: this.getOptions("Shanghai")
        }
      ]
    }
  }，
  methods: {
    getOptions(val) {
      let res = [];
      for(let i=1; i<=5; i++) {
        let floor = Object.create(null);
        floor.value = i;
        floor.label = i;
        floor.children = [];
        for(let j=1; j<=5; j++) {
          let obj = Object.create(null);
          obj.value = j < 10 ? `0${j}` : `${j}`;
          obj.label = j < 10 ? `0${j}` : `${j}`;
          floor.children.push(obj);
        }
        res.push(floor);
      }
      return res;
    }
  }
```

It seems to be correct, but when I select the option, its first and second level data is unchanged. As shown below.

[image]

I have been thinking for a long time and still can't find out why. What surprised me even more is that if my third-level data is stitched with the previous parameters, the results will be displayed normally.

```
  // Can be displayed normally
  // obj.value = j < 10 ? `0${j}${val}` : `${j}${val}`;
  // obj.label = j < 10 ? `0${j}${val}` : `${j}${val}`;

  // This cannot be displayed normally.
  obj.value = j < 10 ? `0${j}` : `${j}`;
  obj.label = j < 10 ? `0${j}` : `${j}`;
```

[image]

Do you know the reason? Please help me with your questions. Thanks！

You can test here: https://jsfiddle.net/DangoSky/7osfp265/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know what the issue is, when you click on the option with the following hierarchy Shanghai > 3 > 03, the library searches top-down of where 03's value is be located. The first hierarchy where 03 is located is Beijing > 1 > 03. Hence it shows the wrong label. This seems to be an issue with the library (or this is how they have designed) because when you use the handleChange method and do a console.log, it prints the value correctly.

To get around the issue, you can have the labels you want but the value needs to be unique to all the options. Something like 'Shanghai+3+03' can be value so that you can split and recover the original values.

Check out the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/n365ecuk/

```
   getOptions(val) {
     let res = [];
  for(let i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    let floor = Object.create(null);
    floor.value = val + '+' + i;
    floor.label = i;
    floor.children = [];
    for(let j=1; j<=5; j++) {
      let obj = Object.create(null);
      // Can be displayed normally
      // obj.value = j < 10 ? `0${j}${val}` : `${j}${val}`;
      // obj.label = j < 10 ? `0${j}${val}` : `${j}${val}`;
      // This cannot be displayed normally.
      obj.value = val + '+' + i + '+' + j;
      obj.label = j < 10 ? `0${j}` : `${j}`;
      floor.children.push(obj);
    }
    res.push(floor);
 }
 return res;
}
```

Comment: I tried it according to the solution you said, but it still didn't work. Can you demonstrate it? Thank you. @cdoshi

Comment: You're right! Thanks. And I use Regular expression to format the data. @cdoshi